# Changing a Preference' Summary

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity, summary

I'm still looking for a way to change the summary of a ListPreference according to its current value. After some research I managed to get it (partially) working:

```
 ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("Repeat_PREFS");

    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object val) {

            ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("Repeat_PREFS");

            pref.setSummary(pref.getEntry());
            return true;
        }

    });
```

The problem is that when I select a value for the first time, the summary changes to some other value or doesn't change at all. When I select the same value for the 2nd time, the summary is set correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not method to do activate the behavior for a preference. You need to call setSummary() with the value you want to set as summary e.g. using a preference listener.

EDIT (after a change to the question ...):
Do not use `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` since it is called before the new value is persisted (cf. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) Hence the behavior for your first change to your preference value.

I recommend to implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity`. (Do not forget to register and unregister the listener.) This listener is called after the change to the preference has been completed. You should also set a default value in the XML for the preferences.

Comment: thanks a lot, I implemented the Listener in my PreferenceActivity and now it works properly! \m/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to SharedPreferences OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, for legacy code (if you can't update all listeners, or do not want to mix SharedPreferences with Preferences):

Use Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener but do not use preference.getEntry(), which would return the old value. Instead, get its new value through the parameter newValue, getting its index in entryValues array and getting the entry by index in entries array.

```
public OnPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //Do not use lp.getEntry(), as it returns the old preference value before being changed
        //Read entry corresponding to entryValue newValue.
        ListPreference lPref = (ListPreference)preference;
        String newEntry = (String) lPref.getEntries()[lPref.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString())];
        //Compose your summary as you need
        preference.setSummary(
            getResources().getString(
                R.string.myPref_summary, newEntry)); 
        return true;    //Persist new value
    }
};
```

This is certainly not performance-friendly, but as long as it will not be run lots of times it could suite you.